# why cant i return opaque types in my swift code? i am already returning a type conforming to that protocol

Tags: swift

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXhvu.png)

As showing in the image, i'm already using types such as `MilkChocolate` which conforms to the "`Chocolate`" protocal, and im trying to declare a function which returns a "`some chocolate`", which means return a type of chocolate depends on the input, but it gives me an error says
`Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types`
this confused me by a lot and i think `MiklChocolate` is an underlying type for the `Chocolate` protocol
whats wrong?
and my code should match this tutorial: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OpaqueTypes.html

PS: if you cant view the image, here's the code

```
protocol Chocolate {
    associatedtype Content
    var mass:Double {get}
}

struct Honey {}
struct Milk {}
struct Wine {}

class HoneyChocolate: Chocolate {
    typealias Content = Honey
    var mass = 1.0
}

class MilkChocolate: Chocolate {
    typealias Content = Milk
    var mass = 1.2
    var mysteriousEffect = true
}

class WineChocolate: Chocolate {
    typealias Content = Wine
    var mass:Double = 999
}

func giveMeChocolate(of type:String) -> some Chocolate {
    switch type {
    case "honey":
        return HoneyChocolate()
    case "milk":
        return MilkChocolate()
    default:
        return WineChocolate()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because Swift can't return different types of generic types. HoneyChocolate and WineChocolate are different types and that causes an issue.

A different way of achieving your goal is to return a `class` type of `Chocolate`.

First let's declare our enum flavors:

```
enum Flavor {
    case Honey, Milk, Wine
}
```

then we will declare the superclass Chocolate:

```
class Chocolate {
    var flavor: Flavor
    var mass:Double
    init(_ flavor: Flavor ,_ mass: Double) {
        self.flavor = flavor
        self.mass = mass
    }
}
```

Now we can inherit this class:

```
class HoneyChocolate: Chocolate {
    init() {
        super.init(Flavor.Honey, 1.0)
    }
}

class MilkChocolate: Chocolate {
    init() {
        super.init( Flavor.Milk, 1.2)
        var mysteriousEffect = true
    }
}

class WineChocolate: Chocolate {
    init() {
        super.init( Flavor.Wine, 999)
        var mysteriousEffect = true
    }   
}
```

finally we can return our chocolates:

```
func giveMeChocolate(of type:Flavor) -> Chocolate {
    switch type {
        case Flavor.Honey:
            return HoneyChocolate()
        case Flavor.Milk:
            return MilkChocolate()
        default:
            return WineChocolate()
    }
}
```

---

**Why some doesn't work**

`some` allows you to return a generic type like and ONLY one type.

for example:

let's make a CandyChocolate class:

```
class CandyChocolate: Chocolate {
    typealias Content = Candy
    var mass = 1.0
    var sweetness
    init(sweetness: int) {
        self.sweetness = sweetness
    }
}
```

Now to return a `some Chocolate` we are allowed to return exactly one type of chocolate:

```
func giveMeChocolate(of type:String) -> some Chocolate {
    switch type {
        case "honey":
            return CandyChocolate(sweetness: 5)
        case "milk":
            return CandyChocolate(sweetness: 3)
        default:
            return CandyChocolate(sweetness: 8)
    }
}
```

Comment: but why i cant use some

Comment: and also, by removing some, it shows me another error: Protocol 'Chocolate' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Comment: @alexzms I have updated the code. Hope it will help!

Comment: yeah i understand your code. you know im learning swift right now and i want to code for the purpose of using the word "some" instead of actually developing a function that can give me chocolate ,and i probably used that word in the wrong way, so how can i use "some", my code should perfectly match this tutorial: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OpaqueTypes.html

Comment: @alexzms I added another explanation. Hope it helps